# What does "[:,:,:, 0:1]" mean?

Tags: python, lambda

I came across a deep learning model, of which part of the code is as follows. What do the multiple colons in `[:,:,:, 0:1]` mean?

```
def get_alpha_xij(input_tensor):
    alpha = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,:, 0:1])(input_tensor)
    x_i_j = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,:, 1:])(input_tensor)    
    return alpha, x_i_j
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a way to slice a multidimensional array. Each colon without anything next to it -except the comma - is choosing all the elements of that dimension. Check https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html